# Issue with Android's ListAdapter.getView() view reuse behavior

Tags: android, android-widget, android-listview

I have a ListView that displays a list of items, each of which has an icon and a few bits of text.

I am making use of the "convertView" parameter of the ListAdapter.getView() method, altering an existing view rather than creating a new one when the parameter is non-null.

I had expected the ListView to recycle old views only after they had scrolled out of the visible viewport, but this appears not to be the case.  It appears that the ListView is providing the same object in the "convertView" parameter on each invocation of ListAdapter.getView().  The single view is rendered to the screen, and then sent in again on the next call to getView().

This poses a significant problem for me, as I wish to modify previously rendered views.  I have a background thread retrieving the icons for items, which takes "considerable" time and would be an unacceptable user interface burden to place within the ListAdapter.getView() view rendering code.

Is there any means to make the ListView not reuse views which are currently displayed on the screen?  I'd like to realize the performance/efficiency gains of view reuse and be able to load the icons in a background thread.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're having a similar problem I had for a while: [Old items visible a while, in listview or gridview, when recycling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11961278/old-items-visible-a-while-in-listview-or-gridview-when-recycling)

You have to "reset" the recycled items of the list at the beginning of getView(). Set them back to progress bar, or invisible, whatever the initial state is. Until they fetch the correct data.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this isn't a temporary issue in my case.  The images are already always set to a default icon when a specific icon is required but must be loaded in a background thread.  The problem is that when this background thread completes and retrieves the image, it may assign the image to an incorrect item.  My implementation would work correctly if views were not recycled until they left the visible viewport.  With only a single view being used to render every item in the list, a background image loading thread simply cannot work.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the issue is that Android is creating an additional, never-rendered temporary view for use in layout/measurement under certain conditions.  My assumption that this view was rendered to the screen was not correct.